# active content property on tab change

Tags: avalondock

I want to create binding in code that will jump when the user is navigating between tabs,
or when ever a tab is created.

I tried to bind the dependency property active content property, and from some reason it doesn't work.

thanks.

Answer (score 11):

What may help is to explicitly set a `TwoWay` binding:

```
<avalondock:DockingManager ActiveContent="{Binding DocumentManager.ActiveDocument,
                                                   Mode=TwoWay}" />
```